# Add a swipe navigation in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation, swipe, viewcontroller

I want to add a second view controller to my project with a swipe navigation (Objective-C). Which is the easiest way?

As you can see in the picture I have these buttons in the first view, I want to add more. I also have a background picture which is not in the picture, is it possible to keep it for both views? So when I swipe to the right the background should't move, only the buttons.
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dh78F.png)

Comment: What will happen when you swipe first row ??

Comment: It should show the second view with other buttons. It's like the second page.

Answer (score 0):

You should have two UIViews on your main view in your viewController, lets say view01 and view02. Both views should have a backgroundColor == clearColor (so you can see your backgroundPicture all the time). Add a GestureRecognizer to both views, so you can catch the users swipe gestures. With the swipes you can move out the view01 from the mainView and move in the view02.

In Detail you should have the skills to add UIView instances to your mainView in your ViewController, the skill to move UIView instances and the skill to add GestureRecognizers to a view and connect it with a target action in which the views are moved in or out. This is too much to write this all here, but maybe you can go on by searching the detail problems step by step. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here What you need is to create **Base Class**

Step1 add New Class (.H . M) add name as BaseViewController

Step2 in View did load method  of BaseViewController set background Image

Step3 : Goto  .h file of your First View Controller

```
  @interface FirstViewController : BaseViewController

  @end
```

Step 4 : also do same for Second View Controller (Replace UIViewController with BaseViewController)

Hope it helps